# How can I test hardware-dependent functions?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I'm writing a Node.js application that use external devices, such as printers and smartcard readers.

I'm trying to write tests for the functions that use these devices, and my ultimate goal would be to setup CI for my project. However, I have no clue if it is possible to mock hardware devices for this purpose, or if it is possible at all.

If that helps, I use the [graphene](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/graphene) module for smartcard readers, and the [node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) module for the printer.

Comment: It depends. Usually you need to mock modules that access devices and not devices themselves.

Comment: can you provide a general description of your test suites? for example in jest you can mock whole modules pretty easily, but generally mocking is possible in all popular test frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you'd be expected to mock the API calls to the modules you use.

To give an example using `node-printer`, in `jasmine`:

```
const printer = require('node-printer');
const myModule = require('module i am testing');

describe('printSomething', function () {
    it('prints something and resolves when it completes', function (done) {
        // Mock the printDirect method on node-printer, to immediately
        // call the success callback. You might need to mock additional
        // methods if you make multiple API calls in one method.
        spyOn(printer, 'printDirect').andCallFake(options => {
            options.success(12345);
        });

        myModule.printSomething('blah').then(result => {
            // To be sure your module is calling the module with the expected
            // arguments, you can check the actual arguments passed.
            expect(printer.printDirect.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([[{
                data: 'the exact data',
                printer: 'PRINTERNAME',
                success: jasmine.any(Function)
            }]]);
            done();
        }).catch(done.fail);
    });
});
```

You can construct similar examples in pretty much any test framework (jest, mocha+sinon, etc.).